# Accessing angular service constructor in Jest testing framework

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, jestjs

I'm struggling to find an answer to the following (and I'll bet it's more than likely that the answer is relatively straightforward)...

I'm unit testing an Ionic 3.4 application using the Jest testing framework and can't figure out how to call an angular service for testing where the constructor initialises the Http object and an InAppBrowser Ionic Native plugin object.

My **package.json** file contains the following configuration:

```
...
"jest": {
    "transform": {
        ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "json"
    ]
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^20.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.31",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "ts-jest": "^20.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.6",
    "tslint": "^5.4.3",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^4.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
},
...
```

My **tsconfig.json** file, located in the src/unit-tests directory (so as to only target that directory and its contents and not interfere with the root tsconfig.json file for the Ionic project), is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions" : {
        "module"                        : "commonjs",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports"  : true,
        "experimentalDecorators"        : true,
        "noImplicitAny"                 : false,
        "removeComments"                : false,
        "locale"                        : "en-GB",
        "alwaysStrict"                  : true,
        "skipLibCheck"                  : true,
        "pretty"                        : true
    }
}
```

The requested service - **providers/settings/settings.ts** - is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class SettingsProvider {

constructor(public http     : Http,
            private _INAPP  : InAppBrowser) 
{  }

// Methods follow here
}
```

This is then used within the **settings.test.ts** file like so:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { SettingsProvider } from '../providers/settings/settings';


let settings = null;

beforeEach(() => {
  // The following works IF the SettingsProvider class 
  // contains NO parameters in the constructor
  settings = new SettingsProvider();
});



describe('Settings service', () => 
{
    // Tests are defined within here
    // using methods supplied by the 
    // SettingsProvider class
});
```

IF I take the parameters out of the SettingsProvider class constructor Jest can run the tests exactly as intended (pass or fail).

With the parameters in place inside the SettingsProvider class constructor Jest chokes when trying to run the test script with the following error:

```
 Test suite failed to run

/ionic-unit/node_modules/@ionic-native/in-app-browser/index.js:20
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/providers/settings/settings:12:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/unit-tests/settings.test.ts:2:18)
```

How do I configure my test script so that Jest recognises the modules that are initialised in the SettingsProvider constructor?

I'm relatively new to unit testing and have been trying to figure out how to accomplish this (but, as you can tell, without much joy so far!)

I appreciate any guidance/advice any developers out there might have on the matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Jest yet - I usually work with jasmine/karma, the default from the @angular team - but can't you use the [Testbed to configure it](https://angular.io/guide/testing)?

With karma/jasmine, you can do something like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        Http,
        InAppBrowser
    ],
})
}));

beforeEach(async(() => TestUtils.beforeEachCompiler([]).then(compiled => {
    fixture = compiled.fixture;
    instance = compiled.instance;
    fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);

})));
```

Comment: Hi Christian - thanks for the contribution. I've deliberately gone with Jest as the set up for using that within an Ionic project is pretty minimal/low impact (having looked at other configurations/installations - and their complexity in laying the foundation for in comparison - for using different testing frameworks within Ionic). I haven't investigated using Testbed within the context of Jest but it's something I could definitely investigate)